# How to import external type into global .d.ts file

Tags: typescript, momentjs, typescript2.0

I'm using Moment.js to handle datetime objects in my TypeScript project. I would like to define an object type that has a key with a value of a type `Moment`.

However, when I add the following to a global definition file (`test.d.ts`), none of the interfaces in that file are found anywhere in the project.

```
import { Moment } from 'moment';

interface Test {
  date: Moment;
}
```

When I try to use the interface in a `.ts` or `.tsx` file I get this TypeScript error:

```
[at-loader] ./src/<examplefilename>.tsx:91:26 
    TS2304: Cannot find name 'Test'.
```

Neither VSCode's TypeScript error checking nor TSLint show any problems with the code.

How can I import a type from an external module for use in a global definition file?

Comment: I would check tsconfig file. In compiler options - typeroots you should have @types path and the path to your typings

Comment: @kimy82, I don't think the issue is there. I can import moment just fine throughout my project but I am unable to import it in my project's `.d.ts` definition files to define a global type in my project that uses the `Moment` type. The rest of my `.d.ts` files are found without configuration and work as long as I don't try to import an external type.

Comment: Is the `d.ts` file with the global also included in your `tsconfig.json` project?

Comment: @MattBierner: Yes. The file and its interfaces are accessible across the project until I add the import statement. At that point the interfaces are no longer found by the compiler and I get the error I posted above.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When file has top-level `import` or `export` statement it is considered as a module. All its' content (types, interfaces, etc.) you are interested in needs to be exported explicitly in that file and imported in those files that need the types.

```
// types.d.ts
import { Thingy } from 'sick-lib';

export declare interface IInterface {
  foo: any;
  bar: any;
  baz: Thingy;
}

// main.ts
import { IInterface } from 'types';

const xyz: IInterface = {
  foo: true,
  bar: false
};
```

Comment: That resolves the issue, thanks!

It is a little frustrating to have to export all my interfaces manually now just because I imported one thing though.

Comment: if use export can remove the declare. `export interface IInterface ....`

Answer (score 57):

With TypeScript 3.3+ (and maybe since the 2.4 because it's the version that added support for dynamic imports), you have better ways to solve this isssue, using either:

```
interface Test {
  date: import('moment').Moment;
}
```

or

```
type Moment = import('moment').Moment;
interface Test {
  date: Moment;
}
```

with no need to export any interfaces ;)

Comment: How would you do this with a custom interface if I were to separate my types? Does this work with extending as well? i.e. `interface IUser extends import ('mongoose').document {}`?

Comment: @Borduhh 's question is solved in my answer.

Comment: ```type Transaction = import("../../../generated/graphql-frontend").Transaction```

Answer (score 18):

Here's an example of a `global.d.ts` file in a Create React App project:

```
declare type RouteProps = import("react-router-dom").RouteProps;

declare interface Xyz extends RouteProps {
  yada: string;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Thank you

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Works perfectly in ts 4.4