# Using globalThis in Typescript

Tags: typescript, global-variables

I am trying to use `globalThis` in TypeScript and I would like some suggestions on how to write it in a better way.
Current implementation is like this:

Create a file **types/global.d.ts** and add inside

```
interface Global {
   foo: string
}

declare let foo: Global["foo"];
```

in **tsconfig.json** add

```
"files": [
  "types/global.d.ts"
]
```

Then in order to set the value of `foo` use

```
(globalThis as any).foo = "The value of foo"
```

What I don't like with this approach is first the boilerplate needed (but I think this cannot be avoided) and second the `(globalThis as any).foo =` expression

Comment: My first question would be the use of globalThis and if there is a solution available that doesn't require it. Can foo be referenced in a local scope or reduced scope rather than using a global object?

Comment: @AustinMehmet for this specific case the use of globalThis is needed. `window` object can still work for me. But the need for a global `foo` is required

Comment: No way to use any higher order wrappers to avoid globalThis either?

Answer (score 76):

## Update 2021 October

*Applies to TypeScript 4.3+*

### Error

> Element implicitly has an `any` type because type `typeof globalThis` has no index signature. ts(7017)

### Solution

```js
declare global {
  function myFunction(): boolean;
  var myVariable: number;
}

globalThis.myFunction = () => true;
globalThis.myVariable = 42;
```

- **IMPORTANT**: This solution only works by declaring variables with `var` (do not use `let` or `const`).

### Background

See the discussion on [TypeScript issue 30139](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30139).

Traditionally, the way to specify a TypeScript declare-block in a Node.js context was as follows:

```js
// Does not work as of October 2021 (TypeScript 4.3+)
declare global {
  module NodeJS {
    interface Global {
      myFunction(): boolean;
      myVariable: number;
    }
  }
}
```

### tsconfig.json: noImplicitAny

Note that this error will be suppressed if the TypeScript setting `noImplicitAny` is set to `false`. It is recommended to enable `noImplicitAny` for better type checking.

Comment: Wow! That `var` instead of `let`/`const` was a life-saver!

Comment: interesting, thanks!! but why only with `var`?

Comment: @GianlucaCasati see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55031001/1164465

Answer (score 19):

*My answer is based on the one by Edward Casanova. I was about to edit it, but there are still quite a few differences to the code that works for me, plus I can now give some additional information on this.*

This is based on **TypeScript 4.3.5**

```js
// typings/globals.d.ts (depending on your tsconfig.json)

export {}

interface Person {
  name: string
}

declare global {
  var someString: string
  var globalPerson: Person
}
```

This does not work without at least one `export` (or `import`) keyword. This turns this file into an ES module, which is necessary for this to work. You can export any of the statements or add an empty `export {}`.

The code above adds types for the following handles:

```js
someString
window.someString
globalThis.someString

globalPerson.name
window.globalPerson.name
globalThis.globalPerson.name
```

On the other side, the following is possible, but the result is different:

```js
export {}

declare global {
  let someLetString: string
  const someConstString: string
}
```

This only adds types for the following handles:

```js
someLetString
someConstString
```

As expected, you cannot assign any value to `someConstString`. This might be useful for some older JS libraries that add the functionality to the global scope instead of exporting it. Libraries still can assign values to `const` in this case because it's just a type, not a real `const`. This `const` is only known to TypeScript code. But be aware that `let` and `const` don't add properties to the global objects `window` and `globalThis`. So, `var` might be the better choice here after all.

Comment: First answer that worked for me, thanks. Obviously you need to put `export {}` at the top. Duh. /s

Comment: This is super useful information that should be included in the official documentation. These differences are so nuanced, it gives people a sense of, "I swear this worked for me before!"

Answer (score 11):

Using a combination of the other answers, here is what ended up working for me.

At the top of the TS file (or in a global typings file):

```
declare module globalThis {
    let myObj: { foo: string };
}
```

```
globalThis.myObj = { foo: 'bar' };
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me in TS 4.0.5 after all other answers didn't!

Comment: Declaration name conflicts with built-in global identifier 'globalThis'

Answer (score 5):

You can use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) in typescript to achieve this.

In your `global.d.ts` file:

```js
export declare global {
  interface Window {
    // add you custom properties and methods
    foo: string
  }
}
```

Now you can use `Window.foo` without typescript warning you.

I wrote a mini blog about this on [dev.to](https://dev.to/cogoo/how-to-set-a-new-property-on-the-window-object-in-typescript-3jeh)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I get an error on `declare global` saying ```TS2669: Augmentations for the global scope can only be directly nested in external modules or ambient module declarations.```

Comment: Edited to add export keyword at the start of line

Comment: I also have the `global.d.ts` file at the root of the project (same directory as tsconfig.json)

Comment: I don't know. Maybe I am missing something. Now I get ```TS2668: 'export' modifier cannot be applied to ambient modules and module augmentations since they are always visible.```

Comment: what version of typescript you using? and what vertion of the typescript compiler: `tsc --v` or `npx tsc --v`

Comment: Version 3.7.2 on both

Comment: How about this: > I also have the global.d.ts file at the root of the project (same directory as tsconfig.json)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204781/discussion-between-nickey-and-c-ogoo).

Answer (score 4):

TypeScript 3.4 introduces support for type-checking ECMAScript’s new `globalThis`.

```js
var x = 1
const y = 2
let z = 3
globalThis.x // ok
globalThis.y // should error, no property 'y'
globalThis.z // should error, no property 'z'
globalThis['x'] // ok
globalThis['y'] // should error, no property 'y'
globalThis['z'] // should error, no property 'z'
globalThis.Float64Array // ok
globalThis.Infinity // ok

declare let test1: (typeof globalThis)['x'] // ok
declare let test2: (typeof globalThis)['y'] // error
declare let test3: (typeof globalThis)['z'] // error
declare let themAll: keyof typeof globalThis
```

You can ready more about it in [the documentation.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#type-checking-for-globalthis)

Comment: globalThis seems to be the future, but I haven't found a way yet on how to extend the globalThis with a typed property using TypeScript. I can do that for the Window interface and window object, but for globalThis I'm still searching for a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I finally ended up with the following solution 
in **global.d.ts**

```
interface Window {
  foo: string
}

declare let foo: Window["foo"];
```

And used it in another file like

> window.foo = "The value of foo"

Comment: any idea on how to use the same approach if you want to give the foo property a custom type? As custom types cannot be imported into the global.d.ts file I'm still looking for a solution to declare the extension of the Window/GlobalThis interface with a property of a custom complex type.

Comment: I don't really know about this issue. But could this https://stackoverflow.com/a/58375303/3414905 be a possible solution?

Answer (score 3):

Found a way. Perhaps a decent workaround

In a "global.d.ts" file at the root of your project, write the following

```
declare global {    
    var [propertyYouWantToAdd]: any; or typeof "anything you want. Perhaps import a class from a module";

//Make sure you use var instead of let or const, as it attaches to the global object.     
}
```

Here's the [reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-8.html#augmenting-globalmodule-scope-from-modules) in the docs

Comment: Actually, this is the only way that works for me (in TS 4.3) to make a property/variable known in the global context (without prefix), in `window` and `globalThis` at the same time. Just the example code is very confusing. You don't need brackets (`[]`). Also, `any` and `typeof` are very uncommon ways to declare a type. It should be something like `var myVar: string;`, or `var myObj: SomeCustomInterfaceOrType;`.

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me using `typescript` version `4.5.4`,

1. Create a new `.d.ts` file with the needed types:

> ```
> export declare global {
>     var foo: string;
>     var goo: string;
> }
> ```

2. Add this file to `tsconfig.json` file (using `files` property)

Answer (score 1):

but if you find alternative to

```
window.foo = 'value of foo'
```

then a simple solution is just

In typescript

> other_var_name is the var holding other_var_value or an object or
> function

```
const foo = 'value of foo';
(global as any).foo;
```

work for me