# What is the difference between declare var and declare const in typescript definitions?

Tags: javascript, typescript, speech-recognition, typescript-typings, typescript-definitions

I recently had a few global variables that I was referencing from a TypeScript file that TypeScript marked with the following error:

```
Property 'msSpeechRecognition' does not exist on type 'Window & typeof globalThis'.
```

So I created added the following code into my `env.d.ts` (generated and referenced in `tsconfig.json` by `create-vue`):

```js
declare const msSpeechRecognition: undefined | SpeechRecognitionStatic;
```

This didn't fix the problem. However, when I switched the code to the following:

```js
declare var msSpeechRecognition: undefined | SpeechRecognitionStatic;
```

The error on the reference to `msSpeechRecognition` disappeared. I understand the differences between `const` and `var` in JavaScript, but what are the differences when using them in type declarations?

I couldn't reproduce this same issue when replacing `SpeechRecognitionStatic` with `string`, so I know it's something related to the `SpeechRecognitionStatic` type. Here is how it looked like (brought from `@types/webspeechapi`):

```js
interface SpeechRecognitionStatic {
    prototype: SpeechRecognition;
    new (): SpeechRecognition;
}
```

Comment: Does https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/by-example.html#global-variables not cover it?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, that suggests that `declare var` and `declare const` work the same except for the value being immutable in the `const` case. That's not the case here since using `var` worked for them.

Comment: note that it also changes the _scope_ of the declared variable. `var` drastically changes where things live.

Comment: How exactly are you using `env.d.ts`? Is it a [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-modifying-module-d-ts.html) or a [script](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/global-d-ts.html)?

Comment: @Bergi I am not sure, I know it was whatever create-vue generates by default. I don’t have any imports in it, but it was a TypeScript declaration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that `msSpeechRecognition` is being accessed from the `window` object as `window.msSpeechRecognition`. [You can only add something to `globalThis` by declaring it with `var`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59459312/using-globalthis-in-typescript). If you want to use `const` instead, you will need to replace references to `window.msSpeechRecognition` with just `msSpeechRecognition`.