How to use jQuery and its plugin in TypeScript without importing the library?
I'm working on a new website for my project jQuery Terminal that use Docusaurus and TypeScript. But I don't want to import the library and bundle it with the project. I want to use jsDelivr CDN for the files so it always get the latest version of the library.
This my code that load the dependency from CDN:
import { useLayoutEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import clsx from 'clsx';

import useIsBrowser from '@docusaurus/useIsBrowser';
import Head from '@docusaurus/Head';

import useScripts from '@site/src/hooks/useScripts';
import './styles.css';

const replReady = () => {
  return (
    globalThis.jQuery &&
    globalThis.jQuery.terminal
  );
}

import { initTerminal, destroyTerminal } from './terminal';

type InterpreterProps = {
  className?: string;
};

const terminal_scripts = [
  'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery',
  'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/combine/npm/jquery.terminal/js/jquery.terminal.min.js,npm/js-polyfills/keyboard.js,npm/jquery.terminal/js/less.js'
]

export default function Interpreter({ className }: InterpreterProps): JSX.Element {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>();

  const isProd = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production';
  const isBrowser = useIsBrowser();
  const isStatic = isProd && !isBrowser && !globalThis.jQuery;

  useScripts(!globalThis.jQuery && terminal_scripts);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    (function loop() {
      if (replReady() && styleReady()) {
        initTerminal();
      } else {
        setTimeout(loop, 100);
      }
    })();
    return destroyTerminal;
  }, []);

  function styleReady() {
    // hack to prevent initalizaing of jQuery Terminal before style is loaded
    return !!getComputedStyle(ref.current).getPropertyValue('--base-background');
  }

  return (
    <>
      <Head>
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net" />
        <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery.terminal/css/jquery.terminal.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        {isStatic && terminal_scripts.map(script => {
          return <script key={script} src={script} />
        })}
      </Head>
      <div className="terminal marker" ref={ref}></div>
      <div className={clsx('term', className)}/>
    </>
  );
};

There are two ways of importing the scripts because Docusaurus runs differently when in dev mode (React) and production mode (SSG).
This works fine except it give TypeScript errors when using:
globalThis.jQuery

I got an error:

Property 'jQuery' does not exist on type 'typeof globalThis'

I've tried to import the d.ts files:
/// <reference path="../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../node_modules/jquery.terminal/js/jquery.terminal.d.ts" />

inside src/types.ts file that I tried to include in tsconfig and importing it in tsx file. But it doesn't work.
is there any way to define globalThis.jQuery in TypeScript? It would be nice if the library was not included with the bundle.
I've also tried:
declare global {
  var jQuery: JQueryStatic;
}

but got error:

Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'jQuery'

In different file I use:
import type { JQueryTerminal, JQueryStatic } from 'jquery.terminal';
import type { Deferred } from 'jquery';


Something in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59459312/using-globalthis-in-typescript might work.

@apokryfos I have no idea why but even adding declare global { var jQuery; } throws an error Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'jQuery'. I do import some stuff from jquery using import type.

You could try declaring the global in a different file under the same folder. TypeScript usually picks those up (or may need a reference).  Personally I think docusaurus should have support for externals the same way that webpack does (and there may be plugins out there that do that, I don't know).
